# how to set Data from database to ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

i have developed an Call recording application. it works absolutely right. i managed to show all recorded audio files to listView and managed to play these files from listView. i Have created a database to show the Caller number into listView. the database is working right and it Inserting and Selecting the data from database. know i want to show the database data into ListView. How can i do this plz help. thanks. i'm uploading the code for you to understand.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    mp = new MediaPlayer();

    // database 
            getData = new CallerDatabase(MainActivity.this);
            getData.open();
            receivedData = getData.retrieveData();
            getData.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+receivedData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    FileDataPathForArrayList();
}

private void FileDataPathForArrayList() {
    // this will show the recorded files into ListVIew
    myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    File files = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
    File list[] = files.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        myList.add(list[i].getName());
    }
```

know how can i show the database data in this ArrayAdapter?

```
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.rowlayout,
            R.id.label, myList);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have to change the ArrayAdapter from this

```
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.rowlayout,
        R.id.label, myList);
```

to this

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.rowlayout,
        R.id.label, receivedData);
```

where receivedData is the folder who receive the data form database and show it into ListView

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to display ...

if you just want to display some text into the rows of the listview, 
here is a good example => http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/

if you want to custom your listview, you need to create custom adaptor for you listview.

Comment: Thank u @bottus but i think you dint cough my Question right. i already created the custom listView. i just dont know how to adjust database data in custom listView.

Comment: What kind of data do you want to show in your list view ?

Comment: it was simple. i was assigning the ArrayAdapter the ArrayList variable because of it the ListView showing the data which i have in the ArrayList. i simply remove the ArrayList variable from ArrayAdapter and assign it the database receivedData variable. that will show the data from the database to my ListView.